# Relation to map groups indicated by an attribute in SQLAlchemy

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following (somewhat legacy) SQLAlchemy classes (simplified here):

```
class Recipe (Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Text)

    ingredients = relationship("Ingredient", order_by="Ingredient.position",
                              backref="recipe", foreign_keys="Ingredient.recipe_id",
                              cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")

class Ingredient (Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ingredients'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipe.id'))
    unit = Column(Text)
    amount = Column(Float)
    item = Column(Text)
    inggroup = Column(Text)
    position = Column(Integer)
```

Now, an ingredient can belong to an `inggroup` (think dairy, vegetables, etc.).

I'd like to modify `Recipe.ingredients` to yield a dict (or whatever suitable structure) of a recipe's inggroups and ingredients contained therein, i.e. something like `{'vegetables': [<Ingredient(2 onions)>, <Ingredient(0.5 kg tomatoes)>], 'spices': <Ingredient(1 pinch salt)>}` etc. Within those groups, I still want ingredients to be sorted by their `position` field. Also note that an ingredient doesn't have to belong to an `inggroup` -- it can be just `None` (and will be, in most cases).

Is that possible with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Python's `itertools.groupby`, and added the following `hybrid_property` to the `Recipe` class:

```
@hybrid_property
def the_ingredients(self):
    return groupby(self.ingredients, lambda x: x.inggroup)
```